# Will a PLB (Personal Locator Beacon) work overseas?

Tags: hiking, trekking, emergencies

I'm starting to do some solo hiking here in Italy, and I'm going to buy a PLB soon. I was wondering if I went to Germany or Australia for example, if I activate the beacon will the beacon still get me the emergency services I would need? Thanks!

Comment: This would probably be better asked on Outdoors.Stackexchange.com

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/144190/in-an-emergency-how-do-i-find-and-share-my-position

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, modern and current PLBs will work world-wide. When activated, they transmit a radio signal, which can be picked up by a network of satellites from anywhere on the earth's surface. Your distress call will be forwarded to a search and rescue organization responsible for the area where you are located.

Comment: I'd add that in addition to SAR be informed, authorities will also try and contact your registered contacts who should have been informed by you as to the general area where you will be expected to be found.

Answer (score -5):

No, according to the manual instructions you cannot take your PLB on a plane and need permission to travel by other means other than private transport. This is due to the battery and you would need to ship your PLB by cargo transport ahead of time which more often than not is impractical. If not for these reasons then you could use a PLB anywhere in the world.

Comment: This depends on the PLB itself, and more specifically the content of Lithium in the battery.  Many PLB's (especially those designed for hiking) will contain <=2g lithium per battery, and thus are allowed in hand luggage on flights. Some others contain 2-8g lithium, which is generally allowed in hand luggage with airline approval.

Comment: The British Airways "Guide to Dangerous Goods" states that BA will allow lithium batteries for personal use in a variety of items, e.g., camcorders, lap-tops.