# September in Dolomites

Tags: weather-and-climate, hiking, nature-and-wildlife, dolomites

I will be doing some hiking in Alpe Di Siusi and Tre Cime from Sept 18 to 22. Is September still a warm sunny month? Or is it going to be colder?

Also,this may sound silly but are there any poisonous snakes in these areas I mentioned?

Comment: possibly related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/145063/hazards-on-road-trip-through-italian-alps/145064

Comment: The [viper or adder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vipera_berus) is widespread through Western Europe, also in the [Dolomites](https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/extinction-countdown/alps-new-viper/). It is venomous but only aggressive in defense. It is hibernatory, so perhaps not so frequently seen in uplands after summer is over. They are common in UK too, but although I spend a lot of time outdoors I have only seen one once.

Comment: Have you tried a weather site, for a long term prediction? They may not do the 22nd yet but they should show you the weather the next 10 days or so. Select the level you will be hiking, as height is a deciding factor.

Comment: The weather forecast for the next few days for Alpe Di Siusi is about 0-10° and rain with temperatures below 0° in the night. The weather in the Dolomites *can* be very nice and warm even long into October or the beginning of November, but the temperature depends on the altitude and as you can see, the weather does not *have* to be nice. It is impossible to predict now how it will be from 18th to 22nd of September.

Answer (score 1):

It is a mountain area, there is always risk of cold weather and snow, even in early fall when in high altitude.

Currently the weather around Tre Cime is on the colder sider with freezing temperature at night.

https://www.mountain-forecast.com/peaks/Tre-Cime-di-Lavaredo/forecasts/2973

Hope for the best, prepare for the worse.

You need proper hiking equipment (boots, clothing ... ) and don't go out alone.